# Asp.net GridView shows the content of the directory when using Chrome

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm facing an issue when dealing with GridViews.

I've got a GridView which displays some data. When I click on any of the rows using IE8 everything is fine and it will display the page associated to it.
When performing the same operation under Chrome, what happens is that the browser is displaying the content of the directory. (This is really awkward as I was expecting the same behaviour as IE8)

I don't know what's going on and I've searched everywhere for similar issues but without luck.

First I thought it could be something related to **EnableViewState**, but after changing the values, everything remains the same.

Here is part of the definition of my GridView:

```
<asp:datagrid id="sGrid" ShowHeader="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"
                CssClass="tablelist" EnableViewState="true" UseAccessibleHeader="true" 
    onselectedindexchanged="sGrid_selectedIndexChanged">

<HeaderStyle CssClass="myHeading"></HeaderStyle>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="myHeading"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="mySummary"></ItemStyle>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            &nbsp;
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="C1">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="myHeading"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="mySummary"></ItemStyle>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            &nbsp;
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="C2">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="myHeading"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="mySummary"></ItemStyle>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            &nbsp;
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>                                           
                </Columns>
```

The method for the row click is as follows:

```
protected virtual string GetRowOnClickScript(DataGridItem item) { 
       return String.Format("rowClick(this,'{0}','{1}','{2}');",          
             ((myAdapter)item.DataItem).C1, 
             ((myAdapter)item.DataItem).C2, 
             ((myAdapter)item.DataItem).C3); 
}
```

RowClick is a js function:

```
function rowClick(sender, C1, C2, C3)
{
  location.href = 'myPage.aspx?c1='+ C1 +'&c2='+ C2 + '&c3=' + C3;
}
```

The function is used like this:

```
if (IsBrowserIE(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]))
{
 e.Item.Attributes.Add("onclick", GetRowOnClickScript(e.Item));
}
else //Chrome
{
  AddAttributesToCell(e.Item.Cells, "onclick", GetCellOnClickScript(e.Item));
}
```

What I believe is that this bit of code here **will only work for IE and not for any other browser!!!**.

**Update:**

Thanks to the help from Yuriy Galanter, we found out that attribution will work regardless of the browser (at least for Chrome).

Comment: Can u show the rest of the grid markup? Also (at least partially) what grid looks like as rendered HTML

Comment: Hi Yuriy, I have added the details for the columns. Just plain information. Do you have any idea why this is happening? Each row uses databound and it is being populated via query.

Comment: What is happening on row click - do you display a link, handle click in server-side code etc. ?

Comment: When loading the page the GridView uses the DataSource property to get all the details. When doing click on the grid it calls something like this:                                                                   protected virtual string GetRowOnClickScript(DataGridItem item)
        {
            return String.Format("rowClick(this,'{0}','{1}','{2}');",
                ((myAdapter)item.DataItem).C1,
                ((myAdapter)item.DataItem).C2,
                ((myAdapter)item.DataItem).C3);
        }

Comment: Getting closer. Can you add this code to main question for clarity and also include code for JS function rowClick?

Comment: Hi Yuriy, I have updated the post with some more details.

Comment: This looks like a correct redirect, how is the call to that function built, meaning where results of ` GetRowOnClickScript` are used - do you display something like `<a onclick=rowClick(...)>` link that calls the funciton?

Comment: Hi Yuri, I think I found something in there. See the post again

Comment: That's a very strange way of assigning `onclick` attribute. But it does exists for other browsers as well, try removing that IF condition and use `e.Item.Attributes.Add` always

Comment: Bingo :) Sometimes you just need an extra pair of eyes

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I've been of great assistance. I've been looking at this for hours and the problem was where you mention. Thanks again!.